# chrome 22 and expiring cookie bug (setting by jQuery.cookie)

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, cookies

Only on Google Chrome 22 (latest stable 22.0.1229.94 m) when I close browser my cookies always expire, even if it is set to 2022 year. I set cookie in Javascript by using plugin for jQuery:
https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

and I do it this way:

```
$.cookie("mycookie", "value", { expires: 365*10, path: 'xxx.pl' });
```

On for example Firefox everything works.

The question is.. why it doesn't work on Chrome? Is it a bug or maybe I've done something wrong.

Comment: What is the question ? if its a bug then report it http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list

Comment: So the question is.. why it doesn't work on Chrome? Is it a bug or maybe I've done something wrong.

Comment: If you don't want your cookies to expire at all, why not use localStorage instead? http://www.html5rocks.com/en/features/storage

Comment: It's weird coz even this work on every browser exclude Chrome. I tried on Chrome but on different computer and then it works. Why it don't want to work on my machine, where can be a reason?